# How can I get the element ref of a component directly in the template?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have certain elements that I set focus to using mouseover as so:

```
<div #divTemplateVar (mouseover)="divTemplateVar.focus()"></div>
```

Although this doesn't seem to work for a component:

```
<component #componentTemplateVar (mouseover)="componentTemplateVar.focus()"></component>
```

I know I can use a

```
viewChild('componentTemplateVar', { read: ElementRef })
```

to select the component in the template, but I have many components that need to just focus themselves on mouseover and don't want to manually write a view child and match their id with the a mouseover function.

How can I get component children to auto focus themselves on the mouseover event?

Answer (score 1):

Make a directive : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reciwu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
export class HoverFocusDirective {

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
  ) { }

  @HostListener('mouseover')
  onMouseOver() {
    this.el.nativeElement.focus();
  }

  @HostListener('mouseout')
  onMouseOut() {
    this.el.nativeElement.blur();
  }

}
```